# Menu not adding sub category for one item but works for other Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a naked wordpress theme. The menu nav bar has 6 items/linked text of these 6, 4 have sub categories with dropdowns showing.

[image: Menu nav bar]

However when I go to add a sub category to one of the items that does not already have a dropdown/sub category it does not display on my site.

I have saved and cleared cache.

When I inspect the html code I have noticed a difference between the successful and unsuccessful. See below:

Successful menu item with sub category in dropdown:

```
<li id="menu-item-7726" class="who has-links menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-7726">
    <a href="/who-we-are/leadership-team/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Who We Are</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30">
            <a href="https://www.website.com/who-we-are/leadership-team/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Leadership Team</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36">
            <a href="https://www.website.com/who-we-are/ireland/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Ireland</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37">
            <a href="https://www.websitee.com/who-we-are/uk/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">UK</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Unsuccessful menu item with sub category not on display:

```
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-23">
    <a href="https://www.website.com/news-hub/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">News Hub</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11549" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-11549">
            <a href="/teampage/" aria-current="page" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Get Social</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I edit the html in the inspector and change the unsuccessful item to this it works:

```
<li id="menu-item-23" class="pj has-links menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-23">
    <a href="https://www.website.com/news-hub/" aria-current="page" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">News Hub</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11481" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11481">
            <a href="https://www.website.com/teampage/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Get Social</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>



<li id="menu-item-23" class="pj has-links menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-23">
    <a href="https://www.website.com/news-hub/" aria-current="page" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">News Hub</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11481" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11481">
            <a href="https://www.website.com/teampage/" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">Get Social</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image: Edit of HTML in inspector]

My question is how/where do I make this edit permanent? TIA

Edit CSS added:

```
ul#menu-main li:hover:after {
width:100%;
}
ul#menu-main li.who:after {
left:-50px
}
ul#menu-main li.se:after {
left:-37px;
}
ul#menu-main li.se:hover:after {
width: 186%;   
}
ul#menu-main li.who:hover:after {
width: 160%;
}
#menu-main .pj.has-links .sub-menu {
left:60px;
}
ul#menu-main li a {
color:#fff;
display: inline-block;
}
.single ul#menu-main li a {
font-weight:500;
font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Medium', sans-serif;
}
ul#menu-main li a:hover {
color:#ffee00;
}
ul#menu-main li.has-links {
position: relative;
}
ul#menu-main li.has-links a:after {
content: '';
background: url(img/chevron-down.svg) no-repeat center center;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background-size: 16px 16px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top:2px;
margin-left:10px;
}
ul#menu-main li.has-links:hover a:after {
content: '';
background: url(img/chevron-active.svg) no-repeat center center;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background-size: 16px 16px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top:2px;
margin-left:10px;    
}
ul#menu-main li.has-links:hover .sub-menu {
-webkit-transform: scale(1) translateX(-50%);
transform: scale(1) translateX(-50%);
visibility: visible;  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the theme's files? The function which handles the output of this menu should be wp_nav_menu() and should be located in header.php

Comment: <div class="head-nav">
        
          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'main') ); ?>
            
          </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when you add a new **child** `menu-item` under an existing **parent** `menu-item` that doesn't have already any **child** `menu-item` under it, the `has-links` class is not added to this particular **parent** `menu-item`.

This is **bizzare** because their must be a `php function` that is generating this class and adding it to each `menu-item` that is becoming a **parent** `menu-item` after putting under it a **child** `menu-item` !
If their is no such `php function`, how did the other **parent** `menu-item` get this class ?!

Also, you have a `php function`, maybe the same one, that is generating a class before the `has-links` class. It's `who` for the **WHO WE ARE** `menu-item`, it's `se` for the **SERVICES** `menu-item`, it's `pj` for the **PROJECTS** `menu-item`, **BUT** it's not generating a class for **NEWS HUB** `menu-item` when it becomes a **parent** !
If their is no such `php function`, how did the other **parent** `menu-item` get those classes depending on their names/labels ?!

You say :

> I have a naked wordpress theme

Is this a theme that you are developing or a theme that you are using ?
Assuming that it's a theme that you are using, could you tell us which one is it.

Finally, for your menu to work, since I don't have your `php` code, I'm going to use the native `CSS` classes added by WordPress for any **parent** `menu-item`.
In the above `CSS` that you provided, replace every `has-links` by `menu-item-has-children`.  It should work !
Remember to use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for your changes or they will be removed on the next update of the theme that you are using.